# Nested headings bit confused on what to do here

Tags: html

So i'm almost done making my website until i got to the Resources part. I'll be real. I have no clue what to do here. So i asked my mate. He told me to look up nested headings. So i looked them up and couldn't really find any information regarding them. Now i do want to apologise if what i'm asking isn't nested headings but rather something else. I've attached a screenshot below of what i'm trying to make my page look like in regards to the links. Any links or information on how to do this would be great!

[image]

Comment: You should ask about your problem, not the solution. Also, try to create a [mcve]

Comment: @DestinatioN I ensure you its not :/

Comment: Looking at your screenshot, I think your rather mean nested *lists*: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899337/proper-way-to-make-html-nested-list

Comment: @chade_ Thanks! guess that what he meant

Comment: Yeah, nah, mate... You're looking for nested lists, aren't ya?
Give this a crack and let us know how it goes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6898013/4603295
Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for here are unordered lists, which are represented in HTML code as <ul> and <li> tags. You can nest them to achieve a layout as shown in your screenshot.

```
<ul>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>bar</li>
            <li>baz</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```